# Matching hexadecimals with gawk

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I have a binary file with the following content (printed in hexadecimal):

```
$ xxd -p virus.com
5669727573b440bb0100b90500ba0000cd21
```

I can match the first 5 letters (which are the alphanumeric string 'Virus') with

```
$ gawk '/\x56\x69\x72\x75\x73/ { print "Match!" }' virus.com 
Match!
$
```

But as soon as I include the 6th letter (which isn't alphanumeric)

```
$ gawk '/\x56\x69\x72\x75\x73\xb4/ { print "Match!" }' virus.com
$
```

won't match anymore.

Why is that so and what can I do to match the whole pattern?

Comment: Your second code works for me with `gawk` 4.0.1.

Comment: That's weird. I just installed 4.0.1 and it still won't work.

Comment: Maybe an alternative ? http://pastebin.com/L9SAeXMc  (The `grep` one requires `bash` or `zsh`.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The `sed` and the `perl` examples do work for me. The `gawk` and `grep` don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably in a UTF-8 locale (check the output of  `locale charmap`).

Use:

```
LC_ALL=C gawk '/\x56\x69\x72\x75\x73\xb4/ { print "Match!" }' virus.com
```

to make sure byte and character mean the same thing.